# Passing Driver.Instance.FindElement parameters as a variable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I specify "By.Xpath" as a variable in

Driver.Instance.FindElement(**Variablename**(ClickAt)).SendKeys(ScrollTimeString);

I am calling a function which will have the parameter "Searchby" which will find the elements on the basis of passed arguments. I dont want to hardcode it like

if Variable = By.Xpath then Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath(ClickAt)).SendKeys(ScrollTimeString);

If variable = By.id then Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.ID(ClickAt)).SendKeys(ScrollTimeString);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a generic method and pass the identifier type and the path in that method and can return the web element according to the identifier type passed.

For example:

```
public WebElement getElement(String identifierType, String pathExpression){
switch(identifierType){
    case "xpath":
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathExpression));

    case "id":
            return driver.findElement(By.id(pathExpression));

    case "tagname":
            return driver.findElement(By.tagName(pathExpression));

    default:
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathExpression));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sameer. I did the same as a temporary solution but now i know that it is not possible so i will stop researching :)